# using cryptojs to decrypt base64-encoded ciphertext with key / iv

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

My ciphertext is encrypted in AES-128-CBC mode with PKCS1 padding. It's base64 encoded as are my keys and IVs. I'm trying to decrypt this ciphertext with CryptoJS but am having some difficulty. Here's my (non-working) code:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
var plaintext = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("..."),
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("..."),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("...") }
);
alert(plaintext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin).length);
</script>
```

All the .'s are base64-encoded strings. From the documentation I'm gathering that CryptoJS uses CBC mode and PKCS7 padding by default.

Any ideas why it's not working?

edit: my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NSmxY/1/

Comment: It may be wise to set it up on http://jsfiddle.net/, along with a test message and test keys.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/NSmxY/1/ . As that example shows the length is 0.